# Reading in external data in d3 JavaScript - an R r2d3 Use Case

Tags: javascript, r, d3.js, r2d3

EDIT: link for all data/code used in example: https://drive.google.com/open?id=16MpDptwV7m4nOkoT3ImlKffl4rYqc5ms

Hello friends and roasters alike,

I'm about as novice as can be with D3 visualization. My background is all in Plotly and integrated R platform plots. I have written very *very* light js/css for Shiny apps, but I'm trying to branch out into more custom and free visual methods.

So I've been diving through the r2d3 package for d3 integration in R. I've searched through all of the examples and pored through whatever documentation I could find in the master repo and overview pages here: https://rstudio.github.io/r2d3/articles/gallery/calendar/

But, for the life of me I simply can't wrap my head around how the js is *actually pulling in the data*

An example here: the visual, following by the script that produces it, and finally the csv provided as the data source to visualize

Visual:
[image: Visual Constructed]

calendar.js script:

```
// !preview r2d3 data = read.csv("dji-latest.csv"), d3_version = 4, 

container = "div", options = list(start = 2006, end = 2011)

// Based on https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063318

var height = height / (options.end - options.start),
    cellSize = height / 8;

var formatPercent = d3.format(".1%");

var color = d3.scaleQuantize()
    .domain([-0.05, 0.05])
    .range(["#a50026", "#d73027", "#f46d43", "#fdae61", "#fee08b", "#ffffbf", "#d9ef8b", "#a6d96a", "#66bd63", "#1a9850", "#006837"]);

var svg = div
  .style("line-height", "0")
  .selectAll("svg")
  .data(d3.range(options.start, options.end))
  .enter().append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + cellSize * 3.5 + "," + (height - cellSize * 7 - 1) + ")");

svg.append("text")
    .attr("transform", "translate(-" + (6 * height / 60) + "," + cellSize * 3.5 + ")rotate(-90)")
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("font-size", 2 + 8 * height / 60)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) { return d; });

var rect = svg.append("g")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "#ccc")
    .attr("stroke-width", "0.25")
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d3.timeDays(new Date(d, 0, 1), new Date(d + 1, 0, 1)); })
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("width", cellSize)
    .attr("height", cellSize)
    .attr("x", function(d) { return d3.timeWeek.count(d3.timeYear(d), d) * cellSize; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return d.getDay() * cellSize; })
    .datum(d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d"));

svg.append("g")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "#000")
    .attr("stroke-width", "0.25")
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(function(d) { return d3.timeMonths(new Date(d, 0, 1), new Date(d + 1, 0, 1)); })
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", pathMonth);

r2d3.onRender(function(csv, div, width, height, options) {
  var data = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) { return d.Date; })
      .rollup(function(d) { return (d[0].Close - d[0].Open) / d[0].Open; })
    .object(csv);

  rect.filter(function(d) { return d in data; })
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(data[d]); })
    .append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d + ": " + formatPercent(data[d]); });
});

function pathMonth(t0) {
  var t1 = new Date(t0.getFullYear(), t0.getMonth() + 1, 0),
      d0 = t0.getDay(), w0 = d3.timeWeek.count(d3.timeYear(t0), t0),
      d1 = t1.getDay(), w1 = d3.timeWeek.count(d3.timeYear(t1), t1);
  return "M" + (w0 + 1) * cellSize + "," + d0 * cellSize
      + "H" + w0 * cellSize + "V" + 7 * cellSize
      + "H" + w1 * cellSize + "V" + (d1 + 1) * cellSize
      + "H" + (w1 + 1) * cellSize + "V" + 0
      + "H" + (w0 + 1) * cellSize + "Z";
}
```

And this is the .csv fed in

[image: screenshot of .csv pulled from github]

And I know this is completely a source of my own understanding of js function call and data handling, but this is simply stumping me to no end. I can see some .data inits and function calls within, but no where do I find any indication of what this visualization is supposed to catch. How does it know which of the columns denotes the dates? Where is the variable specified to actually *visualize*?

Any inkling of help here would be immensely appreciated. I've gotten some d3 tutorials on my horizon, but any pointers can at least get me playing with the sandboxes those smarter than I have built :)

Thank you!

Comment: Pls provide data, no pictures. Check out `?dput`.

Comment: you construct an SVG on the fly, that is the visualization

Comment: @vaettchen I've posted a Google drive link that has all necessary code/data downloadable. Thank you for not yelling at me about missing that formality.

I don't think I follow on the dput lead though

Comment: @rioV8 I guess this may be above my knowledge for some time, but thank you for your response. What I can't grasp is how the SVG understands what data to pull in and how to organize it. E.g. the heatmap included - what are the values here? How is this js script organizing those values? These are the pieces I cannot understand or grasp

Again, if this is simply to neophytic of a question, just let me know and I'll continue researching/learning elsewhere. Thank you for your time

Comment: this is not the place to copy the whole of d3 documentation, you can read it at the d3 site, learn what each and every line of code is doing by reading the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it is an old post... but I ended up here and I think it may be a good idea to write something for further reference.

> How does it know which of the columns denotes the dates? Where is the variable specified to actually visualize?

This example is a bit tricky (or at least misleading) for beginners, but the piece of code specifying the variables/dates is this one:

```
var data = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) { return d.Date; })
      .rollup(function(d) { return (d[0].Close - d[0].Open) / d[0].Open; })
    .object(csv);
```

You can see what exactly `d3.nest` does [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection#nests). In a nutshell, R passes the `data` variable (named `csv` in the js side) to js by translating the table in `dji-latest.csv` to a js-friendly object, like (in R syntax):

```
data <- list(
  list(Date = "2010-10-01", Open = 10789.72, High = ...),
  list(Date = "2010-09-30", Open = 10789.72, High = ...),
)
```

The specific variables are then selected via `d.Dates`, `d.Close` and `d.Open` in `key` and `rollup` function definitions.

Note that `csv` in the function above refers to `data` passed from R, because it is the first argument in the function inside `r2d3.onRender` by default, and that may be the source of confusion. In the js side `csv` is fed to `nest` to produced the nested data object required for this specific visualization.

As others have said, it is hard to give a better explanation than reading the docs and this example is pretty straightforward.